# Unknown connections to foreign hosts

Tags: netstat

When I run netstat -a, a lot of connections to foreign hosts show up. It's connected to a whole subnet, ie 123.123.123.x to the port 80. How can I see what is actually going on? My server doesn't look compromised. It's running ArchLinux.

Comment: Post the output of your that netstat command. Without that, it's quite difficult for us to tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netstat` has a `-p` option that shows you which program is making the connection

```
$ wget http://serverfault.com &
$ netstat -ap
...
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       ID/Program
tcp        0      0 rgb.example.com:1034    stackoverflow.com:http  ESTABLISHED 2578/wget
```

You can then use `ps` to find out what user is running that process, what it's parent process is and other useful info.

You could use `tcpdump dst net 123.123.123` to see what data is being sent and received.